# Prove equality for multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am given that $z=f(x^2+y^2)$ and need to show that $y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$.

Listed below is my attempt. Is this correct? I feel that it seems too simplistic.

$\large{
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = f'(x^2+y^2) \dot{} 2x\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = f'(x^2+y^2) \dot{} 2y
}$

Hence,

$$
\begin{align*}
y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} &= f'(x^2+y^2) \dot{} 2x \times y - f'(x^2+y^2) \dot{} 2y \times x
\\&=2xy \times f'(x^2+y^2) -2xy \times f'(x^2+y^2)
\\&=0
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Is $f$ a real function?

Your calculations are correct, you just need to make sure that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: $f$ is a real function. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem.${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the community, it has been verified as correct.